# Ubuntu 17.04 battery drops significantly in suspend mode

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, battery, 17.04

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on my Dell XPS 13 (9360) and noticed battery drops significantly while put in suspend mode.

Kernel 4.10.0-21-generic

```
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk
```

Graph below for the past ~17 hours mostly in suspend mode.

[image: Graph from Gnome Power Statistics]

The laptop also feels warm while suspended, any fix to this issue?

Running PM_DEBUG log: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/NREvwaLB)

Comment: Could you run and post the output of "cat /sys/power/state" (without quotes) please?

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk freeze mem disk

Comment: The output might help others with resolving the issue too, so it might be a good idea to edit the question to include it.

Comment: So that means your system supports a low-power idle, suspend-to-memory (propably what you want) and suspend-to-disk. Now to find what it actually uses. (accidental submit at this point) Try running "sudo -i" to become root, then "export PM_DEBUG=true" and "pm-suspend". At that point, your pc will be suspended. After it finishes, turn it back on and run and post the last ten lines or so of "/var/log/pm-suspend.log".

Comment: Hmm, there's not enough of the log to see what happens. Can you put more of it there please? (just show the log again)